# How to make a node js endpoint wait for 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node js and have hit a snag along the way. I am creating a rest endpoint for customer place order but before they place order I need to verify some payment from database which happens to be dumped by an external API. My problem is how to instruct my nodejs rest endpoint function not to wait forever for validation payment function and if I call the validation function if it has no data to wait a little bit and recall the same function again to check if data was dumped by external API but if it has elapsed 30 seconds of waiting I respond back to client time out.
Here is my code.

```
controller.placeOrders = async function (req, res, callback)
{
    /**
     * I want to call this method and wait for 30 seconds
     * if no respond I giver user response of time out
     * but if the function has a message 'record found' before 30 seconds elapse it should
     * respond to user immediately
     */
validateCustomerPayment(req.body.amount,req.body.contact,function (result) {
        const code = result.startsWith("record found") ? 200 : 400;
                res.status(200).json({
        message: result,
                code: code,
        });
        }
   );
        
}


/**
 * 
 * @param {type} req
 * @param {type} res
 * @param {type} callback
 * @returns {undefined}
 * this function is waiting for data from some external api
 * so for data to be available for validation the external api must dump data here
 * and dont want the placeOrders to wait forever 
 */
service.validateCustomerPayment = async function (req, res, callback)//this is an exported function
{

Orders.find({PhoneNumber: customer_contact, flag: 'N'}).then((result)=>
{
     if (result != null)
                {
                if (result.length >= 1)
                        {
                        callback("record found");
                                }
                else{
                callback("record not found");
                        }
                }

 }).catch(error=>{
     callback("some error occurred");
 
});
    
          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Node.js > 15 then you can use [timersPromises.setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timerspromisessettimeoutdelay-value-options)

You'd do something like

```
import {pTimeout,} from 'timers/promises';

await pTimeout(30000)
```

pTimeout will return a promise.

Comment: at what point do I add that code?

Comment: In your async function

Comment: If you don't mind you can show me exactly I got 2 async functions. and will this solve my problem?

Comment: Remember my rest endpoint does not need to wait for 30 seconds if the external API has already dumped data in less than 30 seconds

Comment: In this case the promise from the backend should resolve before the one from the timeout and your function should return. To be honnest your code is not very clear to me and it would probably be helpful to see a bit more of it (I'm also only a junior so other might shine in and be more helpful). But I'm guessing it is validateCustomerPayment that you need a timeout for ? I would call it in an async/await function and have my pTimeout there. I would suggest you set up testing and mocking so you can easily troubleshoot and try different solutions. Sorry if I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "setTimeout" function for your need.

```js
let myTimeout = setTimeout(testFunction, 30000);
function testFunction() {
  console.log("Completed Successfully!");
}
```

This piece of code will wait 30 seconds and then execute the function 'testFunction'.